# WCF Fault Exception Line Number

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to get the full exception details in WCF service, however, I am not getting the line number where exception occurs.

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new FaultException(e.ToString());
}
```

I tried various way such as returning `e.StackTrace` etc without luck. Please help me how do I get the line number where exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // Get stack trace for the exception with source file information
        var st = new StackTrace(e, true);
       // Get the top stack frame
       var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
       // Get the line number from the stack frame
       var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
}
```

It'll give you the information you need.

Comment: I already tried it. It doesn't give the line number. It give only message like `Attempted to divide by zero.`

Answer (score 0):

This code would give stacktrace with line number

```
try
{
    ///...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new FaultException<Exception>(ex, ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting this `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have to remove the whole `try` `catch` block:

A even better way would be just commenting it out:

```
//try
//{
      Code.DoSomething(); //of course this code line is only a example and not working

      /*the code inside the try block should now stop on the line, where the error appears*/
      // might look like this: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/images/conditional_logic/Error_Parse.gif
//}
//catch (Exception e)
//{
      //throw new FaultException(e.ToString());
//}
```

You should get something **like** this: (the only image I found on google according to this)

[image: error window]

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Its a WCF service.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was fully in winforms... where's my mind, I thing I might have overread this...